# Error in prolog when parsing xsd using xjc

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation, xjc

I am getting "Error in Prolog" when parsing followinf xsd by xjc

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="info">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="a" type="xsd:string" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

I have checked the validity of the xsd and not getting any error. no character before start also...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with `encoding="utf-16"`. Your file doesn't correspond it.

Set the encoding to something else (e.g. `utf-8`):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```